# hadoop yarn single node performance tuning

Tags: performance, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I have hadoop 2.5.2 single mode installation on my Ubuntu VM, which is: 4-core, 3GHz per core; 4G memory. This VM is not for production, only for demo and learning.

Then, I wrote a vey simple map-reduce application using python, and use this application to process 49 xmls. All these xml files are small-size, hundreds of lines each. So, I expected a quick process. But, big22 surprise to me, it took more than 20 minutes to finish the job (the output of the job is correct.). Below is the output metrics :

> 14/12/15 19:37:55 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
>   14/12/15 19:37:57 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
>   14/12/15 19:38:03 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 49
>   14/12/15 19:38:06 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:49
>   14/12/15 19:38:08 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1418368500264_0005
>   14/12/15 19:38:10 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1418368500264_0005
>   14/12/15 19:38:10 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1418368500264_0005
>   14/12/15 19:38:59 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1418368500264_0005 running in uber mode : false
>   14/12/15 19:38:59 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:39:42 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 2% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:40:05 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 4% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:40:28 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 6% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:40:49 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 8% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:41:10 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 10% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:41:29 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 12% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:41:50 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 14% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:42:08 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 16% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:42:28 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 18% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:42:49 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 20% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:43:08 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 22% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:43:28 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 24% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:43:48 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 27% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:44:09 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 29% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:44:29 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 31% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:44:49 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 33% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:45:09 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 35% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:45:28 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 37% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:45:49 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 39% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:46:09 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 41% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:46:29 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 43% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:46:49 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 45% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:47:09 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 47% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:47:29 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 49% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:47:49 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 51% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:48:08 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 53% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:48:28 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 55% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:48:48 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 57% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:49:09 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 59% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:49:29 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 61% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:49:55 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 63% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:50:23 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 65% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:50:53 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 67% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:51:22 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 69% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:51:50 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 71% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:52:18 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 73% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:52:48 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 76% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:53:18 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 78% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:53:48 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 80% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:54:18 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 82% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:54:48 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 84% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:55:19 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 86% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:55:48 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 88% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:56:16 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 90% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:56:44 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 92% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:57:14 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 94% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:57:45 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 96% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:58:15 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 98% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:58:46 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
>   14/12/15 19:59:20 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
>   14/12/15 19:59:28 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1418368500264_0005 completed successfully
>   14/12/15 19:59:30 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 49
>          File System Counters
>                  FILE: Number of bytes read=17856
>                  FILE: Number of bytes written=5086434
>                  FILE: Number of read operations=0
>                  FILE: Number of large read operations=0
>                  FILE: Number of write operations=0
>                  HDFS: Number of bytes read=499030
>                  HDFS: Number of bytes written=10049
>                  HDFS: Number of read operations=150
>                  HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
>                  HDFS: Number of write operations=2
>          Job Counters
>                  Launched map tasks=49
>                  Launched reduce tasks=1
>                  Data-local map tasks=49
>                  Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=8854232
>                  Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=284672
>                  Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=1106779
>                  Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=35584
>                  Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=1106779
>                  Total vcore-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=35584
>                  Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=1133341696
>                  Total megabyte-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=36438016
>          Map-Reduce Framework
>                  Map input records=9352
>                  Map output records=296
>                  Map output bytes=17258
>                  Map output materialized bytes=18144
>                  Input split bytes=6772
>                  Combine input records=0
>                  Combine output records=0
>                  Reduce input groups=53
>                  Reduce shuffle bytes=18144
>                  Reduce input records=296
>                  Reduce output records=52
>                  Spilled Records=592
>                  Shuffled Maps =49
>                  Failed Shuffles=0
>                  Merged Map outputs=49
>                  GC time elapsed (ms)=33590
>                  CPU time spent (ms)=191390
>                  Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=13738057728
>                  Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=66425016320
>                  Total committed heap usage (bytes)=10799808512
>          Shuffle Errors
>                  BAD_ID=0
>                  CONNECTION=0
>                  IO_ERROR=0
>                  WRONG_LENGTH=0
>                  WRONG_MAP=0
>                  WRONG_REDUCE=0
>          File Input Format Counters
>                  Bytes Read=492258
>          File Output Format Counters
>                  Bytes Written=10049
>   14/12/15 19:59:30 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Output directory: /data_output/sb50projs_1_output

As a newbie to hadoop, for this crazy unreasonable performance, I have several questions:

1. how to configure my hadoop/yarn/mapreduce to make the whole environment more convenient for trial usage?

I understand hadoop is designed for huge-data and big files. But for a trial environment, my files are small and my data is very limited, which default configuration items should I change?  I have changed "dfs.blocksize" of hdfs-site.xml to a smaller value to match my small files, but seems no big enhancements. I know there are some JVM configuration items in yarn-site.xml and mapred-site.xml, but I am not sure about how to adjust them.

2. how to read hadoop logs

Under the logs folder, there are separate log files for nodemanager/resourcemanager/namenode/datanode. I tried to read these files to understand how the 20 minutes are spent during the process, but it's not easy for a newbie like me. So I wonder is there any tool/UI could help me to analyze the logs.

3. basic performance tuning tools

Actually I have googled around for this question, and I got a bunch of names like Ganglia/Nagios/Vaidya/Ambari. I want to know, which tool is best analyse the issue like , "why it took 20 minutes to do such a simple job?".

4. big number of hadoop processes

Even if there is no job running on my hadoop, I found around 100 hadoop processes on my VM, like below (I am using htop, and sort the result by memory). Is this normal for hadoop ? Or am I incorrect for some environment configuration?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't have to change anything.

The default configuration is done for small environment. You may change it if you grow the environment. Ant there is a lot of params and a lot of time for fine tuning.

But I admit your configuration is smaller than the usual ones for tests.

2. The log you have to read isn't the services ones but the job ones. Find them in /var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers/

If you want a better view of your MR, use the web interface on `http://127.0.0.1:8088/`. You will see your job's progression in real time.

3. IMO, Basic tuning = use hadoop web interfaces. There are plenty available natively.
4. I think you find your problem. This can be nomal, or not.

But quickly, YARN launch MR to use all the available memory :

- Available memory is set in your yarn-site.xml : yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb (default to 8 Gio).
- Memory for a task is defined in mapred-site.xml or in the task itself by the property : mapreduce.map.memory.mb (default to 1536 Mio)

So :

1. Change the available memory for your nodemanager (to 3Gio, in order to let 1 Gio for the system)
2. Change the memory available for hadoop services (-Xmx in hadoop-env.sh, yarn-env.sh) (system + each hadoop services (namenode / datanode / ressourcemanager / nodemanager) < 1 Gio.
3. Change the memory for your map tasks (512 Mio ?). The lesser it is, more task can be executed in the same time.
4. Change yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb to 512 in yarn-site.xml to allow mappers with less than 1 Gio of memory.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks so much for your input, @ALSimon. I found no hadoop directory under /var/log, could you tell me the log name pattern, then I could try to search it. For the webinterface, I met some trouble too, and I post a new thread for help : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27517753/hadoop-web-interface-failed-to-show-job-history

Comment: Humm, the log path depends of the hadoop distribution you use. You can try to see in the log4j path (or in the command by doing a ps aux). I have some files of this type : /var/log/hadoop-yarn/yarn-yarn-resourcemanager-hostname.com.log