# hadoop web interface failed to show job history

Tags: hadoop

I could access most functionality  of hadoop admin site, like below:
[image]

But, when I tried to visit the history of each application, I am no luck any more:
[image]

Any body know what happens to my environment? Where should I check?

BTW, when I try to run "netstat -a" on my VM, I found no records for port 8088 or 19888, which is very unreasonable to me, because 8088 lead to hadoop main-page and works well.

Answer (score 1):

In this web interface, you can see your jobs in real time if they are running or the history :
Once a M/R finish, the ressource manager does'nt matter of it. This is the job of the historyServer.

Your historyServer (optionnal part of hadoop YARN) seems not to be launched.
It's this service which listen on 19888.

You can launch it with the command : /etc/init.d/hadoop-mapreduce-historyserver start